# How to disable a combobox with graying it?

Tags: vba, combobox

I need your help to be able to disable combobox with graying it. I'm not sure how to do that.

Thank you !

Comment: Without more information no one can help you. What application is this? What kind of combobox? Where is it located? What do you mean by "disable" and under what circumstances should it happen?

Answer (score 2):

In Ms Access you can do that by

```vb
Me.myComboBox.enabled = false
```

this locks the box and grays it, but without knowing the application you use i am not sure if this will work for you.